# I Am A Human Riley

Tags: riddle

> My prefix in your room, you don’t talk about
>
> My infix in your pants, you can’t sit still
>
> My suffix turns a perfect memory into a rare condition
>
> And though I’ve raised questions of a man’s humanity,
>
> My whole is just swell.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I bet you are

> elephantiasis.

my prefix in your room, you don’t talk about

> "The elephant in the room".

my infix in your pants, you can’t sit still

> Ant(s), as already identified by other solvers.

my suffix turns a perfect memory into a rare condition

> "An elephant never forgets". But add -iasis to "elephant" and you get the rare condition that's the subject of this puzzle.

and though I’ve raised questions of a man’s humanity,

> Perhaps a reference to [The Elephant Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Merrick).

my whole is just swell.

> Elephantiasis is a condition (in fact, it's a name for a few different conditions) causing body parts to swell up monstrously.

Comment: Correct. I’ll keep this puzzle open in hopes that the suffix part can be properly explained. Good luck 

Comment: Oh, wait, I see. Editing in explanation in a moment. [Done now.]

Answer (score 6):

Partial:

My infix in your pants, you can’t sit still:

> Ants (from [Ants in your pants](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/have-ants-in-your-pants))

My suffix turns a perfect memory into a rare condition

> Hyper, see [Hyperthymesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperthymesia) or Highly/Superior, see [HSAM](http://hyperthymesia.net/hyperthymesia/)

Comment: The room I don't talk about is probably my bathroom. WC? Toilet? Restroom?

Comment: @Clearer I don't think so, it's "In your room, you don't talk about"

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure this works, but are you:

> Mr. Fantastic?

My prefix in your room, you don’t talk about

> ?

My infix in your pants, you can’t sit still

> "ant" - see [WELZ's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/64023/38170)

My suffix turns a perfect memory into a rare condition

> Perhaps something to do with a "tic," often associated with rare brain/memory conditions... or "[eidetic memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eidetic_memory)," commonly known as photographic memory?

And though I’ve raised questions of a man’s humanity,

> [Mr. Fantastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mister_Fantastic) is a superhero, and the humanity of superheroes is often questioned

My whole is just swell.

> It's simply fantastic!

And as for the title:

> Well, Mr. Fantastic is at least mostly human, despite being a superhero

Comment: Nobody mentions their fan, it just *is*.

Comment: +1 for creativity 